# JQuery Valdiation - Not required but validate

Tags: jquery, validation

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

I am writing a simple form using the jquery validate plugin.

My first two fields are name and email, these are both required.

My third field is a phone number but is optional.

In each field I have initial values in the text box (e.g. enter your name here, enter your phone here, enter your email here)

I have added elements so that if the field is not altered, it will return the error message.

My problem is I am having issues with the following

1) phone number validation using jquery 
2) validating the phone number box if it isnt required but not throwing a error if the user doesnt type anything and leaves it with the default value

Here is my jquery code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$.validator.addMethod(
'noPlaceholder', function (value, element) {
    return value !== element.defaultValue;
 }, 'Please enter a value.'
 );



 $("#drform").validate({

 rules: {
    name: "required",
    email: "required email",

 },

  messages: {
    name: "Enter your name",
    email: "Enter your primary email address",

},
  category: {
    notEqual: "Enter Your Name Here...",
    notEqual: "Enter Your Email Here..."
},


errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        error.insertBefore(element.prev());
        element.parent().addClass('error');


}

});
    });
    </script>
```

and here is my form code

```
 <div class="is-selection3">
 <div style="width: 200px;">
 <div class="errormsg"></div>
 <input name="name" type="text" size="30" class="is-input noPlaceholder" id="name" onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'Enter Your Name Here...':this.value;" value="Enter Your Name Here..." ><br>
 <input name="email" type="text" size="30" class="is-input"  id="email" onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'Enter Your Email Here...':this.value;" value="Enter Your Email Here..."><BR>
 <input name="mobile" type="text" size="30" class="is-input mobile"  id="mobile" onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'Enter Your Phone Number Here...':this.value;" value="Enter Your Phone Number Here..."> 
 <BR>
 <center><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" /></center>
 </div>
```

Any thoughts on how I can validate if the default is not there but not making it required also?

Answer (score 0):

A tip... try to don't use "onEVENT" attribute, write your javascript actions in javascript files.

About your problem, since HTML5 came up you can use placholder and requeried attributes and add a jquery plugin to handle with browser that doesn't have support for these attributes.

Some plugins for these attributes:

[GitHub - Mathias Byens - jQuery Placeholder Plugin](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder)

[GitHub - Daniel Stocks - jQuery Placeholder Plugin](https://github.com/danielstocks/jQuery-Placeholder)

[Webcloud - jQuery Placeholder Plugin](http://webcloud.se/code/jQuery-Placeholder)

[Ilia Draznin - jQuery Placeholder Plugin](http://www.iliadraznin.com/2011/02/jquery-placeholder-plugin)

[GetHiFi - jQuery Handler to required attribute](http://www.gethifi.com/blog/nmcformhelper)

And what u want with the input for celphone number is a plugin for mask input inputs :]

[DigitalBush - Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin)

[Webappers - jQuery Masked Input Plugin](http://www.webappers.com/2008/04/22/jquery-masked-input-plugin)

[Conetrees - jQuery Masked Input Plugin](http://www.conetrees.com/2009/03/blog/jquery-masked-input-plugin-increase-usability-for-masked-format-input-fields)